# How to convert AsyncPageable foreach loop to parallelforeach loop in .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a below await foreach loop written in .Net core 3.1 c# and need to convert it to parallel foreach loop

```
     AsyncPageable<Participant> details = chatThreadClient.GetParticipantsAsync();

                await foreach (ChatParticipant participant in details)
                {
                    participants.Add(participant.User.ToString());
                
                }
```

Comment: If you want to use [Parallel.ForEachAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreachasync?view=net-6.0) Method`,it is not supported in .Net core 3.1.

Comment: Yes it only works in .Net 6

Answer (score 0):

if you modify code following way it will work

```
 var details =await chatThreadClient.GetParticipantsAsync();

       foreach (var participant in details)
          {
            participants.Add(participant.User.ToString());
          }
```

Comment: Yes i had tried this.. but problem is  GetParticipantsAsync method doesn't implement GetAwaiter

Comment: If that is aync function you need to use await. if not no need of await key @user1037747